# Why sed command does not recognize my regex to change date format?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm studying Regex and I faced a example that convertes dates formats:

`sed -r 's|([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})|\3/\2/\1|' <<< 05/04/1947`

Output:

`1947/04/05`

I understand why this works but I'm not sure why the author used `|` 'pipe' instead of '/' to separate the regexp, replacement and flags sections.

I think changing `|` to `/` would make the same output:

`sed -r 's/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})/\3/\2/\1/' <<< 05/04/1947`

Why the last example does not work like the first one?

Thanks!

Comment: The first char behind `s` is the parameter separator. And the separator can be any char, but must not part of regex or replacement. In your example you use `/` as character, so it is forbidden.

Comment: @Wiimm Thanks! Now I got it.